# Проблема кодировки веб-страницы на русском языке (Python 3.8)

Tags: python, кодировка

Я пытаюсь распарсить страницу на русском языке, но в место читаемого текста выдает непонятное кодировку.

Мой код ниже:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
response = requests.get('http://helpmetest.ru/avtorskoe_i_patentnoe_pravo/spisok_1.html')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

heading = soup.find('h3')
heading_data = heading.text
#print(heading)

print(heading_data)
```

Выводит следующий ответ :

`ÐžÑ‚Ð²ÐµÑ‚Ñ‹ Ð½Ð° Ñ‚ÐµÑÑ‚Ñ‹ Ð¿Ð¾ Ð´Ð¸ÑÑ†Ð¸Ð¿Ð»Ð¸Ð½Ðµ Â«ÐÐ²Ñ‚Ð¾Ñ€ÑÐºÐ¾Ðµ Ð¸ Ð¿Ð°Ñ‚ÐµÐ½Ñ‚Ð½Ð¾Ðµ Ð¿Ñ€Ð°Ð²Ð¾Â»`

Comment: `response.text` -> `response.content`

Comment: Или так `soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text.encode('ISO-8859-1').decode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')`

Comment: response.content помог.

Comment: Да там и второй вариант поможет, просто это костыль. Для парсинга используйте `response.content` проблем будет в разы меньше